# I am using django(1.8.6), displaying and operations on page are very slow in admin site..!

Tags: python, django, django-views

To fix this I imported `'ENGINE': 'django_mysql_fix.backends.mysql'` but getting below error.

`from django.db.backends.mysql.compiler import SQLInsertCompiler, \
ImportError: cannot import name SQLDateCompiler`


Any fix to speed up the page view because I`ll be working on more data in future..!

Comment: You seem to have squeezed in every single development problem you ever had into one question.

Comment: Admin pages with slow loads are often due to dropdowns for foreign keys containing lots of entries. Try switching those to raw_id_fields.